# Finite fields: Is multiplicative order of $x^p - x - 1$ equal to $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ over GF(p)?

Tags: finite-fields

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiplicative order of zeros of the Artin-Schreier Polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46133/multiplicative-order-of-zeros-of-the-artin-schreier-polynomial)

I will be grateful for any reference to some literature on the following question (to the best of my knowledge the answer is not known):

Is multiplicative order of roots of $x^p - x - 1$ equal to $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ over $GF(p)$?

Brief Note:
$P(x) = x^p - x - 1$ is irreducible. (Proof: Observe that composition with $x+1$ does not change $P$, so if polynomial Q(x) is a factor than Q(x+a) is also a factor.) Norm($x$) = 1, so the maximum possible order for $x$ is $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$.

Comment: I believe you mean the multiplicative order of **a root of** $x^p-x-1$...

Comment: Sure! (just saving space)

Comment: By the way: To the best of my knowledge currently there are no known nontrivial series of irreducible polynomials over finite fields with known mult. order at all. I do not expect a direct answer to this question, rather a reference to some relevant literature.

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46133/multiplicative-order-of-zeros-of-the-artin-schreier-polynomial

Comment: Agreed! (Found it myself). How can I delete the question?


Comment: It's better to close it as a duplicate than to delete it. That way, if somebody has the same question in the future, they have a better chance of finding the right thread (i.e. different wordings will effectively point to the same place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see papers of mine (on Bell numbers) with coauthors and papers of sam wagstaff.

Comment: It might be a good idea to cite such papers more exactly and give links if possible. 

Comment:     Luis, 

could you please give some more details on the paper citation (e.g title, year, conference/journal). 

Comment: According to Mathscinet there is one paper by Gallardo on this topic: Car, Mireille; Gallardo, Luis H.; Rahavandrainy, Olivier; Vaserstein, Leonid N. About the period of Bell numbers modulo a prime. Bull. Korean Math. Soc. 45 (2008), no. 1, 143–155.